# Creating a trigger where if one field is null another automatically is

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying the create trigger where if one field in my database is null then automatically update another to be null. This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t123
BEFORE INSERT ON Customer
  REFERENCING NEW ROW AS New
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
IF new.f is null 
THEN       
    new.course_year = null;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: And what is the issue? are you having an error, a wrong behaviour, ... ?

Comment: `new` is a reserved word, so try using another name, for example: `REFERENCING NEW ROW AS New_row`.

Comment: Or just use the proper syntax as [specified in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the `REFERENCING`, you can simply use `:NEW`.
Also, outside a `WHEN` clause, you have to use `:NEW` and not `NEW`:

```
SQL> create table customer ( f varchar2(100), course_year varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TRIGGER t123
  2      BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  3      ON Customer
  4      FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6      IF :new.f is null
  7      THEN
  8          :new.course_year := null;
  9      END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into Customer(f, course_year) values (123, 123);

1 row created.

SQL> update customer set f = null, course_year = 'test';

1 row updated.
SQL> select * from customer;

F          COURSE_YEA
---------- ----------


SQL>
```

Comment: I have changed INSERT to UPDATE, and then updating in my object browser what is was hoping would happen is that if I entered null into field f and 'test' into course_year field. The course year field would be updated to null. But the 'test' value seems to be staying even though the trigger has been created successfully?

Comment: thanks! I think I was confusing leaving the field blank and entering the word null into the field :)

Comment: Oracle and SQL Server behave differently for the empty string. Oracle treats the empty string as a null, SQL server treats it as an empty string, non-null, which I believe is the ANSI behavior. If by blank,you mean empty string, those raised on SQL Server will get unexpected behavior. If by blank you mean a space, both databases treat it the same.

Comment: @BrianLeach: the question is only tagged Oracle, so I gave on Oracle specific answer. In questions tagged with more DBMS, it would be right giving answers working for all the involved DBMS, or at least specify in the answer the DBMS for which the answer is supposed to work.

Comment: @Aleksej: you answered entirely appropriately. and correctly. I am not certain what I was thinking when I  added the clarification.